# Is profanity allowed in answers or questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

I have never seen anyone swear in a question or an answer, but I haven't seen any rules regarding profanity either. I'm just wondering: is there some sort of regulation against profanity, or is it generally just frowned upon? I am pretty new to the community so please forgive me if there is some obvious rule I have overlooked.

Comment: Can you find any reason profanity would be allowed?

Comment: @Dani So we can say the actual name of Brainfuck, for example.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, profanity is not allowed in questions or answers.

[Are expletives (cursing, swear words or vulgar language) allowed on SE sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-allowed-on-se-sites)

In addition to the professionalism issue, there's also the matter of being blocked by corporate proxies based on inappropriate language.

Answer (score 1):

It's generally frowned upon, I think. There aren't any formal rules, but this is a professional site. I would suspect that if your post had profanity in it, someone would edit it away.

My personal rule of thumb is that if I wouldn't say it at work, then it doesn't go into a post here.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see why it might be even remotely necessary to be honest.